# pip3 install mysql-python failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4nev4id4/mysql-python/

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip, mysql-python

I am new in python on flask, when i try to install mysql-python by entering the
following command in terminal

```
pip3 install mysql-python
```

it shows the following error:

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4nev4id4/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4nev4id4/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4nev4id4/mysql-python/
```

and then I use this command
 `sudo apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev` in terminal which has been suggested by many i checked on stackoverflow.

and then I retry to install mysql-python but also it is showing the same error, can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysql-python](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) only supports Python 2.x, while you seem to be using Python 3. From the linked PyPI page:

> MySQL-3.23 through 5.5 and Python-2.4 through 2.7 are currently
>   supported. Python-3.0 will be supported in a future release.

To connect to MySQL from Python 3 you can use other alternatives:

- [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)
- [mysql-connector-python](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector-python/)
- [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)
- [cymysql](https://pypi.org/project/cymysql/)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL-python does not support python3. That is why you get this particular error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

In python3 `ConfigParser` is renamed `configparser`

One option to connect to MySQL DB is [official python connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)

Another option is [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc)

Other options are provided in other answers